# What should we do about the "Torcheck" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag, "[torcheck](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torcheck)" is defined as:

> TorCheck is a website hosted by the Tor Project for determining if a visitor is using Tor or not. It is usually a user's first step in identifying if their Tor connection is configured correctly.

However, I've noticed so many questions under the "torcheck" tag which do not even relate to https://check.torproject.org.

So what exactly should we do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend removing the tag from the questions. In my opinion it doesn't make any sense to have questions with a "wrong" tag. Furthermore I can't really imagine any good questions which can belong to this tag. So in general it might be a good idea to remove the tag at all.

Comment: I've edited a lot of questions which used this tag incorrectly. However, a few questions legitimately used the torcheck tag. So perhaps we should keep it, but just make sure it isn't used incorrectly.